# Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in 'E:\React Projects\Project 8\redux\node_modules\react-redux\es\connect'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

After installing redux trying to run application but getting error like "can't find the module". Why this not working.
AND I tried thses but still can't find the error."npm install --save redux react-redux","npm install --save redux"....

Now Please help me what should i do?

Comment: Does your project have a folder called `redux`? That commonly causes problems like this.

Comment: yes i install redux before...

Comment: now what i do ?

Comment: Okay thanks i understand what i have to do...Thanks For your help

Comment: as @phry mentioned, I changed the folder name from redux to another name, it worked :)